# Question's Views Increasing When Its Author Views Its Edit History

Tags: bug, questions, views

I noticed something unexpected that I think may be a bug.

If a question's author views the question (which is quite common of course), SO does *not* increment the question's views in my experience.  This is what I would expect.

*However*, if a question's author views the question's *edit history* (which is also quite common), SO *does* increment the question's views.  This is *not* what I would expect.

From what I observed and confirmed through experimentation, this seems like a reliable way for authors to game their questions' views - not a good thing.

Is this expected behavior, or am I correct that this is odd and likely a bug?

Comment: My experience is that I have 2 questions that are attracting no feedback or anything, but every time I refresh the page to see if anything has happened - the view count goes up by 1.  This has happened on a 2 month old question, that nobody has left any feedback on. Except I have revisited it today and refreshed 4 times, and now it has gone from 37 to 41. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074113/eclipse-java-application-dynamically-importing-jars-from-another-application)